# Bitbucket Pipelines. Cannot specify windowsservercore docker image

Tags: docker, .net-core, bitbucket-pipelines

Bitbucket Pipelines allows (using `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`) to specify a custom docker image from Dockerhub as build environment. Next image is used as default for .NET Core:

```
# You can specify a custom docker image from Dockerhub as your build environment
image: microsoft/dotnet:onbuild
```

But cause I need Windows Containers image, I am trying to change image to "windowsservercore". Based on information in [microsoft/dotnet](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet/) docker hub,  I have tried

```
image: microsoft/dotnet:1.0.0-windowsservercore-core
```

and

```
image: microsoft/dotnet:1.0.0-preview2-windowsservercore-sdk
```

but image has not been downloaded:

```
+ docker pull "microsoft/dotnet:1.0.0-windowsservercore-core"
1.0.0-windowsservercore-core: Pulling from microsoft/dotnet
1239394e5a8a: Pulling fs layer
d90a2ac79ff2: Pulling fs layer
cde3fa87b2c9: Pulling fs layer
9f60be4f8205: Pulling fs layer
c4f6347ed968: Pulling fs layer
9f60be4f8205: Waiting
c4f6347ed968: Waiting
1239394e5a8a: Retrying in 5 seconds
d90a2ac79ff2: Verifying Checksum
d90a2ac79ff2: Download complete
cde3fa87b2c9: Verifying Checksum
cde3fa87b2c9: Download complete
1239394e5a8a: Retrying in 4 seconds
c4f6347ed968: Verifying Checksum
c4f6347ed968: Download complete
...
1239394e5a8a: Retrying in 3 seconds
1239394e5a8a: Retrying in 2 seconds
1239394e5a8a: Retrying in 1 second
1239394e5a8a: Downloading
unknown blob
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might not be able to use that image at all if Bitbucket pipelines [doesn't support running Windows images yet](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/92#issuecomment-238260148)...

> The error you are reporting, is the error you get when a windowsservercore or nanoserver image is pulled from an unsupported host.

Additionally, my local docker does the same when running that pull.

```
$ docker pull microsoft/dotnet:1.0.0-windowsservercore-core`. 
1.0.0-windowsservercore-core: Pulling from microsoft/dotnet
1239394e5a8a: Downloading 
d90a2ac79ff2: Download complete 
cde3fa87b2c9: Download complete 
9f60be4f8205: Download complete 
c4f6347ed968: Download complete 
unknown blob
```

You can have a look detailed look via the Registry API at the `1.0.0-windowsservercore-core` tags manifest:

```
curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" https://index.docker.io/v2/microsoft/dotnet/manifests/1.0.0-windowsservercore-core
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 4168
Content-Type: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v1+prettyjws
Docker-Content-Digest: sha256:190e1596bf49b844f6fc3361bbedcd50c917079e5f9f305a1fe807ae4b66a6a7
Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
Etag: "sha256:190e1596bf49b844f6fc3361bbedcd50c917079e5f9f305a1fe807ae4b66a6a7"
Date: Sun, 07 Aug 2016 13:25:58 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000

{
   "schemaVersion": 1,
   "name": "microsoft/dotnet",
   "tag": "1.0.0-windowsservercore-core",
   "architecture": "amd64",
   "fsLayers": [
      {
         "blobSum": "sha256:9f60be4f8205c0d384e6af06d61e253141395d4ef7000d8bb34032d1cbd8ee98"
      },
      {
         "blobSum": "sha256:cde3fa87b2c91c895014a6c83481b27ede659f502538c6ed416574a3abe5a7a2"
      },
      {
         "blobSum": "sha256:d90a2ac79ff2c769b497fabddbd14ae8a66f8034dda53fd5781402ec58416989"
      },
      {
         "blobSum": "sha256:1239394e5a8ab79fbd3b751dc5d98decf5886f14339958fdf5c1f96c89da58a7"
      }
   ],
```

The manifest includes the `1239394e5a8` blob Docker is not able to retrieve. Then running a GET for that blob returns a 404.

```
curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" https://index.docker.io/v2/microsoft/dotnet/blobs/sha256:1239394e5a8ab79fbd3b751dc5d98decf5886f14339958fdf5c1f96c89da58a7
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
Date: Sun, 07 Aug 2016 13:29:02 GMT
Content-Length: 157
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000

{"errors":[{"code":"BLOB_UNKNOWN","message":"blob unknown to registry","detail":"sha256:1239394e5a8ab79fbd3b751dc5d98decf5886f14339958fdf5c1f96c89da58a7"}]}
```

Whereas that other blobs return the usual redirect to the data download:

```
curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" https://index.docker.io/v2/microsoft/dotnet/blobs/sha256:d90a2ac79ff2c769b497fabddbd14ae8a66f8034dda53fd5781402ec58416989
HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
Location: https://dseasb33srnrn.cloudfront.net/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/d9/d90a2ac79ff2c769b497fabddbd14ae8a66f8034dda53fd5781402ec58416989/data?Expires=1470577758&Signature=B6n1cC~fNwgeYYbA2w6peZOWM5RyV79OrBW-9nN2NdxpB60FC1sUe7e9I4kcA7Meq1SAG7z4P4gQiLvNfokHr8u0p3LTUQgk4JpqZPxqSPNtDWoSyjzyTN0sK3iZPhgxcNBVfddHyxgkAw7xb47zUg76RjZ5-O8QNl2YeEKeX24_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJECH5M7VWIS5YZ6Q
Date: Sun, 07 Aug 2016 13:29:18 GMT
Content-Length: 432
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000

<a href="https://dseasb33srnrn.cloudfront.net/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/d9/d90a2ac79ff2c769b497fabddbd14ae8a66f8034dda53fd5781402ec58416989/data?Expires=1470577758&amp;Signature=B6n1cC~fNwgeYYbA2w6peZOWM5RyV79OrBW-9nN2NdxpB60FC1sUe7e9I4kcA7Meq1SAG7z4P4gQiLvNfokHr8u0p3LTUQgk4JpqZPxqSPNtDWoSyjzyTN0sK3iZPhgxcNBVfddHyxgkAw7xb47zUg76RjZ5-O8QNl2YeEKeX24_&amp;Key-Pair-Id=APKAJECH5M7VWIS5YZ6Q">Temporary Redirect</a>.
```

It's probably a registry bug and the MS dotnet team might need to rebuild that layer/image and publish again to work around the [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/92). Once they've fixed that you will find out if Bitbucket pipelines can run Windows images (which I've found no evidence to say they do yet).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this by using the mono docker image and xbuild.